# Function not defined using onkeyup for table search

Tags: javascript

Using similar functionality as the [table search](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_table.asp) at w3schools, I'm getting an error that the function used for the `onkeyup` is not defined on the input element. The name of the function is the same, so this shouldn't be an issue.

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
<div class="container form-container">
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 search-form">

<input type="text" id="search" onkeyup="tableSearch()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Search by Name, Practice Area or Location">
      </div>
</div>

<div class="results">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div id="no-more-tables">
        <table id="results" class="order-table col-md-12 cf">
            <thead class="cf">
                <tr>
                    <th class="numeric">field 1</th>
                    <th class="numeric">field 2</th>
                    <th class="numeric">field 3</th>
                    <th class="numeric">field 4</th>
                    <th class="numeric">field 5</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

                <tr>
                    <td data-title="" class="name"><a href="user-1">User 1</a><a href="tel:(407) 420-1414"><span class="phone"><i class="fa fa-phone phone"></i></span></a><a href="mailto:user1@site.com"><span class="email"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o email"></i></span></a></td>
                    <td data-title="location"></td>
                    <td data-title="practice area" class=""></td>
                    <td data-title="email" class="numeric desktop-only"><a href="mailto:user1@site.com">user1@site.com</a></td>
            <td data-title="phone" class="numeric desktop-only"><a href="tel:(111) 111-1111">(111) 111-1111</a></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td data-title="" class="name"><a href="user-2">User 2</a><a href="tel:1111111111"><span class="phone"><i class="fa fa-phone phone"></i></span></a><a href="mailto:user2@site.com"><span class="email"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o email"></i></span></a></td>
                    <td data-title="location"></td>
                    <td data-title="practice area" class=""></td>
                    <td data-title="email" class="numeric desktop-only"><a href="mailto:user2@site.com">user2@site.com</a></td>
            <td data-title="phone" class="numeric desktop-only"><a href="tel:1111111111">1111111111</a></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function tableSearch() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  input = document.getElementById("search");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("results");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");


  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {

    tds = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
    var found = false;
    //---second loop that goes over all tds in a tr ---can be modified as required to go over only certain tds
    for (j = 0; j < tds.length; j++) {
      td = tds[j];
      if (td) {
        if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
          found = true;
          break;
        }
      }
    }

    if (found)
      tr[i].style.display = "";
    else
      tr[i].style.display = "none";

  }
}
```

**JSFIDDLE: [LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/3dzxhpkL/)**

Answer (score 0):

Your method `tableSearch` is in `onload` **Load-Type** in your fiddle's **Javascript Options**, hence it is not in a global scope.

Check the updated [fiddle's](https://jsfiddle.net/3dzxhpkL/1/) **Javascript** options. I have selected '**Wrap in head**' to put it in global scope so that it is accessible from an event handler.

Comment: I see. The other issue is that the table headers disappear on search, though they should be staying visible, as they do in the w3schools version.

Answer (score -1):

maybe you can use the jquery library

```
$( "#search" ).keypress(function() {
  tableSearch();
});
```